# How to set notification icon background of windows 10 application as transparent?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I built simple c++ Windows Form project with Visual Studio 2015.

My application has toast (Windows 10), and that shows icon like this.

[image: Toast]

Application icon has transparent background.
How can I remove blue background of icon?

Source Code: https://github.com/chaeyk/SoundDeviceToggle

Comment: It is better to post code in your question.  Try to narrow your code down to the smallest amount that shows your problem.

Comment: Icon is automatically put by Windows. My code sets text only.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @ToreØstergaard Nope. So, I removed popup. :)

Comment: Btw, did you do anything to get the icon to be that size? I seem to only get icons half that size no matter what I do.

Comment: I have also tried to seek help (no jokes please) here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, A bit late BUT ... in my effort to try and help

... Did you try both a transparent pixel PNG?[png here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVRVy.png)
... and/or a transparent pixel GIF?[gif here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVxzl.gif)
( see 2 attached 1x1px images )

NOTE: I'm not sure what filetype you may need, but the same instance applies.  If anyone wants me to supply a transparent image of a certain type eg. png, ico etc let me know.

Else, you can easily generate transparent PNG's ...
https://png-pixel.com/
and
https://onlinegiftools.com/create-1x1-pixel-gif